# react-table v6 get data in a row by index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Don't want to migrate to v8, so looking for solution

consider I have some headers and the data looks like
[{value: 1, value: 'zxv', value: 'd53'}]

So I want to match my headers with that data by index: first header match first value in an array and so on.

Any options?

Comment: Can you share your current code to get more context?

Comment: Does this work: columsnArray = columnsArray.map(
(col, i) => {
col.id = i; // required when the accessor is not a string
col.accessor = (d) => d[i];
return col;
}); ?

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs here we go. I want to match table's column (header) ID with the data that comes from server by mathing their index only https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qbqhgy?file=src/App.js

Comment: Noticed your comment, will have a look and let you know

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs there is also an issue, when there are many items in the data array with indexes higher than 100 (as items repeat for many rows)...

Comment: What do you mean? Вы говорите по-русский? Можете написать по-русски

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs well, actually I have an array of arrays for the rows: 0: [{value: "195"}, {value: "2022-10-11 05:34:39"l},…] and there could be many rows. I flat that array into one and it becomes one huge array. Will that solution solve it?

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs that's what I mean https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-edgooj?file=src/App.js

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs thank you. it worked     col.accessor = (d) => d[i].value;

Comment: Great! Will be glad to help if something is unclear regarding this code

Answer (score 1):

Does it help you?

```
import ReactTable from "react-table-v6";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      name: "Tanner Linsley",
      age: 26
    },
    {
      name: "Tanner Linsley",
      age: 26
    },
    {
      name: "Tanner Linsley",
      age: 26
    },
    {
      name: "Tanner Linsley",
      age: 26
    }
  ];

  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "Name"
    },
    {
      Header: "Age"
    }
  ].map((col, i) => {
    col.id = `${i}`; // required when the accessor is not a string
    col.accessor = (d) => Object.values(d)[i];
    return col;
  });

  return (
    <ReactTable data={data} columns={columns} />
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-andras-9njtov?file=/src/App.js

This one is my adaption of your sandbox on StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wsumxr?file=src%2FApp.js